# Login with Requests - Not capturing redirects

Tags: python

I am trying to learn requests module and was practice logging to a website but for some reason the it is not working and i am unable to login.

```
import requests
import sys

param1 = sys.argv[1]
param2 = sys.argv[2]

url2 = 'https://myhpgas.in/myHPGas/Login.aspx'

with requests.Session() as s:
    s.get(url2)
    print(r.headers)
    payload = {'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$txtUserNameEmail': param1,
               'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$txtPassword': param2}
    p = s.post(url2, data=payload, headers=headers)
    p.raise_for_status()
    r = s.get('https://myhpgas.in/myHPGas/HPGas/User/ConsumerConsole.aspx')
    print(r.text)
```

Session cookie.

```
{'ARRAffinity': 'ab2cda67a33c1a756e728834a3f88bc425b66b583804aee440e53c204539d683'}
```

Request headers for POST request

```
{'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/57.0.2987.133 Safari/537.36', 'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate', 'Accept': '*/*', 'Connection': 'keep-alive', 'Cookie': 'ARRAffinity=ab2cda67a33c1a756e728834a3f88bc425b66b583804aee440e53c204539d683', 'Content-Length': '125', 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
```

Response headers for POST request

```
{'Cache-Control': 'private', 'Content-Length': '7404', 'Content-Type': 'text/html; charset=utf-8', 'Content-Encoding': 'gzip', 'Vary': 'Accept-Encoding', 'Set-Cookie': '.CZONEAUTH=; expires=Mon, 11-Oct-1999 18:30:00 GMT; path=/; HttpOnly', 'X-AspNet-Version': '4.0.30319', 'X-Powered-By': 'ASP.NET, ARR/2.5, ASP.NET', 'Date': 'Fri, 05 May 2017 13:49:59 GMT
```

This is how form data from browser looks like

```
tsmManager_HiddenField:
__EVENTTARGET:
__EVENTARGUMENT:
__LASTFOCUS:

__VIEWSTATE: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

__EVENTVALIDATION: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
ctl00$ddlSelectLanguage:-1
ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$txtUserNameEmail:emailid@domain.com
ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$txtPassword:password
ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$btnLogin:Login
```

And below are the request headers that the browser is sending

```
Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Cache-Control:max-age=0
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:1678
Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Cookie:ARRAffinity=ab2cda67a33c1a756e728834a3f88bc425b66b583804aee440e53c204539d683; _csm_ux_data=; ASP.NET_SessionId=dxonrup25fyldmnwvhuakv4y
Host:myhpgas.in
Origin:https://myhpgas.in
Referer:https://myhpgas.in/myHPGas/Login.aspx
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests:1
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/57.0.2987.133 Safari/537.36
```

So can someone let me know what i am missing here ?

Comment: you need to set `status code` as `302` in your login api code, your `http post request` will always return `200` since it only checks response

Comment: Can u pls explain a bit more on how to do that.I think the website that i am using returns 302 only, i checked this is firefox and post returns 302.

Comment: I am getting `HTTP/1.1 200 OK` as response

Comment: Were you able to login to the website and see the welcome message ?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to parse the GET response and then extract the dynamic values from html source and then posted them in POST request, that resolved my issue.